# Filtering strings that contain a dollar sign

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to list all of the shares on a computer that aren't hidden. But I just can't get the where-object clause to work. Any idea how I would filter out all of the share names that have a dollar sign in them? Right now this filters nothing out.

```
$ComputerName = "server"
$Shares = get-wmiobject -class Win32_share -ComputerName $ComputerName 
$Shares | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.Name.tostring() -notcontains "\`$" }
```

I know this is simple, but I just can't figure it out.

edit:
Here's my resulting script if anyone wants to copy (names changed to protect the innocent):

```
$ComputerNames = "server1","server2","server3","server4"

$Shares = invoke-command $ComputerNames { get-wmiobject -class Win32_share } -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue"
$Shares | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.Name.tostring() -notlike '*$*' }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how it compares to containment operators for speed, but I would use a match operator to do this:

```
$Shares | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.Name.tostring() -notlike '*$*' }
```

Comment: That does it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Like @EBGreen said, should do:

```
$Shares | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.Name.tostring() -notlike '*$*' }
```

Reason being is that `-notcontains` is used for array searching.

Comment: Well, if you really really wanted to use a containment operator, in this specific case you could do: **$Shares | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.Name.ToCharArray() -notcontains '$' }**